# Shell Merge several consecutive lines with Only Digit different

Tags: shell, awk, sed

Recently I met an issue to write a tool to  Merge several consecutive lines with Only Digit different.
For Example:

```
show plim xge-plim registers port 0
show plim xge-plim registers port 1
show plim xge-plim registers port 2
show plim xge-plim registers port 3
show ethernet infra internal vlan-ma global
show ethernet infra internal vlan-ma subs
```

I want to change it to

```
show plim xge-plim registers port <number>
show ethernet infra internal vlan-ma global
show ethernet infra internal vlan-ma subs
```

Is there any way to do this? I had thought it for days....

Figures in the below one, should not be deleted, leave it so.
show tech-support routing ospfv3 terminal
show tech-support routing ospfv2 terminal
show tech-support routing ipv4 terminal
show tech-support routing ipv6 terminal

Below one is expected to be deleted.

show plim xge-plim registers port 8
show plim xge-plim registers port 9
show plim xge-plim registers port 10
show plim xge-plim registers port 11

change it to
show plim xge-plim registers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{sub(/[0-9]/,"<number>")} !seen[$0]++' file
show plim xge-plim registers port <number>
show ethernet infra internal vlan-ma global
show ethernet infra internal vlan-ma subs
```

Comment: Dear, your smart program, really solve my example issue.

Comment: show tech-support routing ospfv3 terminal
show tech-support routing ospfv2 terminal
show tech-support routing ipv4 terminal
show tech-support routing ipv6 terminal

yet, these number, I do not want to change and delete, is there any way to avoid deleting this kind of figures？

and also the following situation is not the expecting result. 

show plim xge-plim registers port 8
show plim xge-plim registers port 9
show plim xge-plim registers port 10
show plim xge-plim registers port 11

Thank you so much,man.

Comment: Don't try to put formatted text (input, output, code) in a comment as you can't. If the sample input and output in your question isn't representative of your real input/output then edit your question to fix it. Use the `{}` editor button for format your text btw. If, after you've done that, you post a comment addressed to me here I'll take a look. Really THINK about what input/output you need to process this time though as I won't come back to this question a 3rd time. Alternatively just post a new question.